# Create Tensor with images and lable jpg vs png

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I try to create a tensor out of images for an CNN.
First i used jpg images and that works well. The Tensor includes the number of images, the shape and the channels. Therefor i take all images in a directory an put it in an np array, something like this:

```
dataset=[]
for img in glob.glob('dataset/*.jpg')
   bild=cv2.imread(img)
   dataset.append([bild,split_lable(img)])
```

( also tried [np.array(bild),split_lable(img)] )For the CNN i split the lable and the images like this:

```
X=np.array([i[0] for i in dataset])
Y=np.array([i[1] for i in dataset])
```

this works very well and i geht exactly what i want.

> X | Array of uint8 | (655,337,900,3)

But now i want to use some png images. I just change the direction and the ending to png but this will return an array of type object

> X | array ofobject | (610,)

So here the number of images is correct but i miss the size. I can't see any Differenz in how i safe the images in the array especially because the individualy images have the right type.

Comment: as I can see all of the jpg images has same resolution, this is why you get the array dimension right, the pngs could have different resolutions or different number of channels (3 or 4) and thats why numpy reads it as object

Comment: @AlyHosny that was the problem, thank you. Somehow 4 images out of the 600 managet to have the wrong resolution